# Improving ArcGIS Pro Basemap Quality when exported to PDF?

Tags: export, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online-basemaps

Since making the switch to ArcGIS Pro all of my exports (to PDF) have poor Basemap quality, especially the World Topographic basemap and the Light Gray Canvas Basemap. The export settings I used for ArcMap are the same for ArcGIS Pro.

Any suggestions?

Comment: At first I wanted to tell that you need to check DPI of the output *.PDF file. I made it 600. But the quality is still too poor to share. Something deeper is inside this case.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if it was the **Image Quality** setting. Mine was set to Normal, changing it to Best fixed the base map quality.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try printing to a PDF print driver.

That seems to fix many of the issues coming out of the Export to PDF option.

Answer (score -1):

I've had good luck sticking to the coordinate system and scales the basemap was designed for. Couple of things to try:

1. [Use the basemap's native coordinate system](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/properties/specify-a-coordinate-system.htm) (likely WGS 1984 Web Mercator).
2. [Modify your list of scales](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/map-scales-and-scale-properties.htm), loading the ArcGIS Online/Bing Maps/Google scales, and be sure to use one of the scales included in that list.

[image: Customizing the list of scales]
[image: Loading the AGOL scales]